# did not call through to "super.onPostCreate()" when using Google Play Services API

Tags: java, android, google-plus, google-play-services

To allow Google+ sign in for Android. I must use Google Play Services API. I am using the exact code from [this article about G+ sign in](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/). However. Every time this is run I am being redirected from my OnClickListener's  and GoogleAPIClientBuilder to the Play Service class called ActivityThread.

Within ActivityThread, the code that I land to is:

```
 if (!activity.mCalled) {
       throw new SuperNotCalledException(
        "Activity " + r.intent.getComponent().toShortString() +
        " did not call through to super.onPostCreate()");
}
```

I have tried changing the code from:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

    // Button click listeners
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}
```

to:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    btnSignOut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
    btnRevokeAccess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
    imgProfilePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
    txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
    llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);

}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Button click listeners
    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
}
```

This change made no difference and the activity was still being sent to the same "did not call through to super.onPostCreate()" section.

This does not seem to be affecting only OnCreate but any time Google Play Services is used throughout this activity.

I am unsure why this occurs, is it a problem to do with how I have added Google Play Services or should I be using different code?

Comment: I just upgraded to the latest GooglePlayServices and now am receiving the same error on my startup activity that does not even override onPostCreate.  I just started researching this, but my assumption is that this has nothing to do with the activity that is active at the time of the error

Comment: Getting this error as well - I recently changed an ArrayAdapter to a BaseAdapter, and now when I try to call setListAdapter(baseAdapter), the exception is thrown. But maybe Rich is correct